# Импорт функции из другого файла в одном пакете Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x

Решаю учебную задачу. Нужно импортировать функцию из соседнего файла, т.е. находящегося в одном каталоге. Файл называется Ch4_Function_Steph.ipynb (скопировал). Функция def ordinalNumber(num): (скопировал)

В новом файле вызываю:
from Ch4_Function_Steph import ordinalNumber

Получаю ошибку:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Ch4_Function_Steph'

Сделал !pip install nbimporter, не помогло.
Ставил точку перед именем файла .Ch4_Function_Steph, не помогло

Comment: импортировать можно только модуль/из модуля. Файл .ipynb - не модуль, а собственный файл Jupyter Notebook, поэтому импортировать из него не получится.

Comment: Интересный оборот события. Т.е. если бы я писал в PyCharm, а не в Jupyter то тогда файл был бы модулем и все было бы ОК. А так, получается, что ничего сделать нельзя?!

Comment: если бы писал в пичарме, то файла ipynb вообще бы не было. Разберитесь откуда импортировать надо, вряд ли в задаче написано, что импортировать нужно из ipynb

Comment: это так, не сказано откуда надо импортировать :). А может при создании функции надо было что-то указать, чтобы в последствии можно было ее импортировать? Или как-то создать модуль... А то обидно за JN...

Comment: да, надо как-то создать модуль

Comment: Спасибо за ваши комментарии. С этой проблемой, как я понял, сталкиваются многие и она не имеет простого решения!

Comment: это элементарная вещь описанная в каждом или почти каждом учебнике